# Merge arrays of objects with new key names in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, key, javascript-objects

Any help would be appreciated.

I have an array (A) that contains 3 arrays of objects.

```
A = [
[{date: '2022-12-05', value: 10.6},{date: '2022-12-06', value: 5.6},{date: '2022-12-07, value: 8.6}],
[{date: '2022-12-05', value: 4.2},{date: '2022-12-06', value: 12.3},{date: '2022-12-07, value: 9.5}],
[{date: '2022-12-05', value: 5.6},{date: '2022-12-06', value: 9.8},{date: '2022-12-07, value: 7.8}]
]
```

From this array (A), I need to get an array (B) that will contain the merged/concatenated arrays with new / renamed object keys (value1,value2,value3)  as per the following format:

```
B =  [
{date: '2022-12-05', value1: 10.6, value2: 4.2, value3: 5.6},
{date: '2022-12-06', value1: 5.6, value2: 12.3, value3: 9.8},
{date: '2022-12-07', value1: 8.6, value2: 9.5, value3: 7.8}
]
```

The length of the first array (A) may vary (1 / 2 / 3 or more), this is why I'm struggling to find a dynamic/efficient solution.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and collect all values.

```js
const
    data = [[{ date: '2022-12-05', value: 10.6 }, { date: '2022-12-06', value: 5.6 }, { date: '2022-12-07', value: 8.6 }], [{ date: '2022-12-05', value: 4.2 }, { date: '2022-12-06', value: 12.3 }, { date: '2022-12-07', value: 9.5 }], [{ date: '2022-12-05', value: 5.6 }, { date: '2022-12-06', value: 9.8 }, { date: '2022-12-07', value: 7.8 }]],
    result = Array.from(
        data
            .flat()
            .reduce((m, { date, value }) => m.set(date, [...m.get(date) || [], value]), new Map),
        ([date, values]) => values.reduce((o, v, i) => ({ ...o, [`value${i + 1}`]: v }), { date })
    )
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) functions:

```js
const A = [
  [{date: '2022-12-05', value: 10.6},{date: '2022-12-06', value: 5.6},{date: '2022-12-07', value: 8.6}],
  [{date: '2022-12-05', value: 4.2},{date: '2022-12-06', value: 12.3},{date: '2022-12-07', value: 9.5}],
  [{date: '2022-12-05', value: 5.6},{date: '2022-12-06', value: 9.8},{date: '2022-12-07', value: 7.8}]
];

const B = A.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  curr.forEach(item => {
    const existingItem = acc.find(i => i.date === item.date);
    if (existingItem) {
      existingItem[`value${A.indexOf(curr) + 1}`] = item.value;
    } else {
      acc.push({
        date: item.date,
        [`value${A.indexOf(curr) + 1}`]: item.value
      });
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(B);
```

Comment: That is quick, thanks so much. I often struggle with this type of problem in JavaScript and React.js. How can I improve my programming skills, do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: There is places, like leetcode, where you could practice such problems.

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest a simpler data structure? Instead of numbering through the values in the form of 'value1, 'value2', ... 'valueN', you could use an array of values per date, which would make the transformation also a little bit easier as well:

```js
const A = [
  [{date: '2022-12-05', value: 10.6},{date: '2022-12-06', value: 5.6},{date: '2022-12-07', value: 8.6}],
  [{date: '2022-12-05', value: 4.2},{date: '2022-12-06', value: 12.3},{date: '2022-12-07', value: 9.5}],
  [{date: '2022-12-05', value: 5.6},{date: '2022-12-06', value: 9.8},{date: '2022-12-07', value: 7.8}]
]

//Flatten Array
const Af = A.flat();

//Group by date
const B = Af.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur['date']] = acc[cur['date']] ? [...acc[cur['date']], cur.value] : [cur.value]
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(B);
```